# Get the old element before replacement, not the new one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with JavaScript, I used this function to replace all  to 
then when I use jQuery to get the new element  by ID, It returns the old one

```
/**
 * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
 */
    jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });
```

Then after converting all  to . when I want to deal with the `<svg>` in JavaScript, it's just not working:

```
// <img id="search"> => changed to <svg> => <svg id="search">
$('#search').css('fill', 'red'); // it's not working
// to check if the element I got is the correct one:
console.log($('#search')); //the result is the old <img> !??
```

Comment: `jQuery.get()` is asynchronous; you need to wait until all those requests have finished before doing stuff to the `<svg>`s.

Comment: Hi @Hades welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure this is the answer, but since you have only posted snippets and not the whole document I can only guess. `jQuery.get` takes time, and it may even fail if the given URL is incorrect. So if the bottom code block occurs before the image is actually loaded, you will get what you describe.

Comment: @ReedSpool Thank you for the answer, but the function that uses (jQuery.get()) I used to change All img to SVG is done, but when I call the new element that changed to SVG, I get the old one <img> not <svg> (by ID)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the answer, but the function that uses (jQuery.get()) I used to change All img to SVG is done, but when I call the new element that changed to SVG, I get the old one <img> not <svg> (by ID)

Comment: @Hades do you mean it's "done" as in the second code block comes after the first, so it must have run already? That logic unfortunately (annoyingly) doesn't work in JavaScript, because "async" calls like `jQuery.get` do not "block" the rest of the code from executing.

Comment: @ReedSpool thanks a lot, and sorry for my ignorance, so what do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: @Hades No problem at all, that's what this site is for :) The solution depends on your end goal, but the easiest way to show would be to move the second code block inside the "callback function" to `jQuery.get` in the first code block. That is, just below the line `$img.replaceWith($svg);`